# d3js v5: Create a SVG with groups from a JSON file

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am new to d3js and I want to create the following SVG from a JSON file. I am using d3js version 5.16.

```
<svg width="1024" height="700">
    <g id="gp_node1">
        <rect x="0" y="50" width="1024" height="10" id="node1"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node1">
            <circle cy="200" r="10" id="node1"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textnode1">node1</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="gp_node2">
        <rect x="0" y="100" width="1024" height="10" id="node2"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node2">
            <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="10" id="subnode2"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textsubnode2">subnode2</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It worked (except the attributes) but I do not think, that it is the best way to do it, especially the update function (had to comment the return). The code I ended up with is:

```
var json = {"mainnodes":[{"name":"node1","y":50,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode1","x":100}]},{"name":"node2","y":100,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode2","x":200}]}]};
var json2 = {"mainnodes":[{"name":"node1","y":50,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode1","x":100}]},{"name":"node2","y":150,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode2","x":200}]}]};

var data = json;
var structure;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 1024)
                    .attr("height", 700);
                            
function update(){
    structure = svgContainer.selectAll("g")
                .data(data.mainnodes)
                .join(
                    function(enter) {
                    return enter
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("id",function(d){return "gp_"+d.name;})
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("x",0)
                     .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
                     .attr("width",1024)
                     .attr("height",10)
                     .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;})
                     .each(function(d) {
                          var g = d3.select(this.parentNode)
                         .append("g")
                         .attr("id",function(d){return "gm_"+d.name;})
                         
                          g.data(d.subnodes)
                         .append("circle")
                         .attr("cx",function(d){return d.x;})
                         .attr("cy",200)
                         .attr("r",10)
                         .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;});
                         
                          g.data(d.subnodes)
                         .append("text")
                         .attr("x",0)
                         .attr("y",10)
                         .attr("id",function(d){return "text"+d.name;})
                         .text(function(d){return d.name;});
                     })
                    },
                    function(update) {

                      var s = d3.select("g");
                      s.attr("id",function(d){return "gp_"+d.name;});
                      
                      s.select("rect")
                     .attr("x",0)
                     .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
                     .attr("width",1024)
                     .attr("height",10)
                     .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;});
                     
                      var g = s.select("g");
                      g.attr("id",function(d){return "gm_"+d.name;});
                     
                      g.select("circle")
                     .attr("cx",function(d){return d.x;})
                     .attr("cy",200)
                     .attr("r",10)
                     .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;});
                     
                      g.select("text")
                     .attr("x",0)
                     .attr("y",10)
                     .attr("id",function(d){return "text"+d.name;})
                     .text(function(d){return d.name;});
                     
                     //return update;
                    },
                    function(exit) {
                      return exit;
                    }
                )                                                                   
}
d3.select('svg').on('click', function(){
    data = json2;
    update();
})
update();
```

In all examples I saw so far the enter function had only one element appended (so update and exit is always is referring to this one element only). But if I split the append functions up into separate joins, I am not able to get the SVG structure I need. I already tried a lot of variations. Maybe someone can show me how to do it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it (if I am not allowed to change the data structure?). Does this help? If I can change the data structure, I can do it easier and cleaner. Since D3 is "Data Driven Documents", I normally start with that.

```js
const json = {
    "mainnodes":[
      {"name":"node1","y":50,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode1","x":100}]},
      {"name":"node2","y":75,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode2","x":25}]}
    ]
};
const json2 = {
    "mainnodes":[
      {"name":"node3","y":50,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode1","x":100}]},
      {"name":"node4","y":150,"subnodes":[{"name":"subnode2","x":200}]}
    ]
};
const data = [json, json2];
let currIndex = 0;

const svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1024)
      .attr("height", 700);

function update(data){
  
  const parentGroups = svg.selectAll('.gp')
      .data(data.mainnodes);
      
  parentGroups.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr('class', 'gp')      
      .merge(parentGroups)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attr("id",function(d){return "gp_"+d.name;});

  const gr = parentGroups.selectAll('.gr')
      .data(d => [d]);
      
  gr.enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'gr')        
        .merge(gr)
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
          .attr("x",0)
          .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
          .attr("width",1024)
          .attr("height",10)
          .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;}); 

  const subGroups = parentGroups.selectAll('.gm')
      .data(d => [d]);
   
  subGroups.enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'gm')
      .attr("id",function(d){return "gm_"+d.name;})
      .merge(subGroups)
      .transition()
      .duration(750);

  const c_shapes = subGroups.selectAll('.circles')
      .data(d => d.subnodes);
  
  c_shapes.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'circles')
      .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;})
      .merge(c_shapes)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attr("cx",function(d){return d.x;})
        .attr("cy",200)
        .attr("r",10);   
   
  const t_shapes = subGroups.selectAll('.texts')
      .data(d => d.subnodes);
  
  t_shapes.enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'texts')
      .attr("id",function(d){return "text"+d.name;})
      .merge(t_shapes)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)      
        .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
        .attr("y",230)        
        .text(function(d){return d.name;});
  ///*
  parentGroups.exit().remove();
  gr.exit().remove();       
  subGroups.exit().remove();        
  c_shapes.exit().remove();      
  t_shapes.exit().remove();  
  //*/
}

console.log('start');

//not ideal, I think there is a way to avoid it but it is not coming to mind...
update(data[currIndex]);
update(data[currIndex]);
update(data[currIndex]);

svg.on('click', function(){    
    currIndex = (currIndex + 1) % 2;
    //console.log('click', 'currIndex: ' + currIndex);
    update(data[currIndex]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- desired output:
<svg width="1024" height="700">
    <g id="gp_node1">
        <rect x="0" y="50" width="1024" height="10" id="node1"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node1">
            <circle cy="200" r="10" id="node1"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textnode1">node1</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="gp_node2">
        <rect x="0" y="100" width="1024" height="10" id="node2"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node2">
            <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="10" id="subnode2"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textsubnode2">subnode2</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
-->
```

Output:

[image]

An alternative approach, changing the data structure and using `d3-selection-multi`:

```js
const json = {
    "mainnodes":[
      {"shape":"g","name":"gp_node1",
        "subnodes":[
          {"shape":"rect","name":"rectnode1","width":1024,"height":10,"y":50,"x":0},
          {"shape":"g","name":"gm_node1",
            "subnodes":[
              {"shape":"circle","name":"circlenode1","cy":150,"cx":200,"r":10},
              {"shape":"text","name":"textnode1","text":"subnode1","y":170,"x":200},
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {"shape":"g", "name":"gp_node2",
        "subnodes":[
          {"shape":"rect","name":"rectnode2","width":1024,"height":10,"y":75,"x":0},
          {"shape":"g","name":"gm_node2",
            "subnodes":[
              {"shape":"circle","name":"circlenode2","cy":150,"cx":100,"r":10},
              {"shape":"text","name":"textnode2","text":"subnode2","y":170,"x":100},
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
const json2 = {
    "mainnodes":[
      {"shape":"g","name":"gp_node3",
        "subnodes":[
          {"shape":"rect","name":"rectnode3","width":1024,"height":10,"y":50,"x":0},
          {"shape":"g","name":"gm_node3",
            "subnodes":[
              {"shape":"circle","name":"circlenode3","cy":150,"cx":250},
              {"shape":"text","name":"textnode3","text":"subnode3","y":170,"x":250},
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {"shape":"g", "name":"gp_node4",
        "subnodes":[
          {"shape":"rect","name":"rectnode4","width":1024,"height":10,"y":100,"x":0},
          {"shape":"g","name":"gm_node2",
            "subnodes":[
              {"shape":"circle","name":"circlenode2","cy":150,"cx":100},
              {"shape":"text","name":"textnode2","text":"subnode4","y":170,"x":100},
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
const data = [json, json2];
let currIndex = 0;

const svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1024)
      .attr("height", 700);

function update(data){
  
  const parentGroups = svg.selectAll('.gp')
      .data(data.mainnodes);
      
  parentGroups.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr('class', 'gp')      
      .merge(parentGroups)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;});

  const subGroups_d1 = parentGroups.selectAll('.gm')
      .data(d => d.subnodes);
   
  subGroups_d1.enter()
      .append(d => document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", d.shape))
      .attr('class', 'gm')
      .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;})
      .merge(subGroups_d1)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attrs(d => {
          const copy = {...d}
          delete copy.shape;
          delete copy.name;
          return copy;
        });
        
  const subGroups_d2 = subGroups_d1.selectAll('.gn')
      .data(d => d.subnodes || []);
  
  subGroups_d2.enter()
      .append(d => document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", d.shape))
      .attr('class', 'gn')
      .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;})
      .merge(subGroups_d2)
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attrs(d => {
          const copy = {...d}
          delete copy.shape;
          delete copy.name;
          return copy;
        })
        .text(d => d.text || ""); 

  ///*
  parentGroups.exit().remove();       
  subGroups_d1.exit().remove();        
  subGroups_d1.exit().remove();        
  //*/
}

console.log('start');

//not ideal, I think there is a way to avoid it but it is not coming to mind...
update(data[currIndex]);
update(data[currIndex]);
update(data[currIndex]);

svg.on('click', function(){    
    currIndex = (currIndex + 1) % 2;
    //console.log('click', 'currIndex: ' + currIndex);
    update(data[currIndex]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>

<!-- desired output:
<svg width="1024" height="700">
    <g id="gp_node1">
        <rect x="0" y="50" width="1024" height="10" id="node1"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node1">
            <circle cy="200" r="10" id="node1"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textnode1">node1</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="gp_node2">
        <rect x="0" y="100" width="1024" height="10" id="node2"></rect>
        <g id="gm_node2">
            <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="10" id="subnode2"></circle>
            <text x="0" y="10" id="textsubnode2">subnode2</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
-->
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Yes, it helps. It is much more structured and more readable. Unfortunately the data structure cannot be changed because it is used by other applications too. I thought since version 5 a join function instead of a merge function should be used but I prefer your way.